# How to set child view to autofill the "other-axis" of the parent's flex direction in react native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

For example, I have this layout:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "column", width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: "gray" }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 50, backgroundColor: "red" }}/>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 50, backgroundColor: "blue" }}/>
</View>
```

This will produce 2 little rectangles with width=50 and height=100 each. The height automatically set to 100 because of flex 1 and parent flexDirection of "column".

My question is, how to red and blue rectangle to have width that follow parent's width automatically? I cannot use "flex" on child for this of course, because the flex is reserved for vertical axis because of the parent flexDirection "column". I'm quite new to even CSS and react native, so this flex system perplexing me.

Comment: Just remove `width` from the child components

Comment: @VilleKoo is right... You can check out the snack project https://snack.expo.io/@torresho/flexboxtest ... Perhaps can improve flexbox knowledge using this https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that in flex display, the children component will be defaulted to follow the parent's cross-flexDirection. And the flexboxfroggy helps!

Comment: Along with FlexBoxFroggy, I've found myself referencing this [CSSTricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a lot. A good visual guide :)